# MVVM binding CaptureElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I know that this topi repeated but i try this solutions ... :(

Okey, I write application on Windows Phone 8.1. This application is QRCode scanner  in MVVM pattern. I have problem with binding CaptureElement bacuse Visual Studio returns error :

```
WinRT information: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as '%1' was not found in type '%0'.
```

Okey, my code XAML :

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="Camera"   Height="300" Width="399.999969482422" Source={Binding ViewCapture}"></CaptureElement>
```

and, ViewModel

```
 private MediaCapture _viewCapture;
 public MediaCapture ViewCapture
        {
            get
            {

                return _viewCapture;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_viewCapture != value)
                {
                    _viewCapture = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `Source` property of `CaptureElement` Its value is the `MediaCapture` but the preview of the `MediaCapture` has not been started.

These two instructions must be executed sequentially:

```
captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

I haven't found an elegant solution to include these two instructions in MVVM. I have used a `ContentControl` element to generate the `CaptureElement`dynamically, inside the ViewModel.

View:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="captureElement"
                Content="{Binding CaptureElement}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainView : BaseView
{
    private CaptureElement _captureElement;
    public CaptureElement CaptureElement
    {
        get
        {
            return _captureElement;
        }
    }

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeCamera();
    }

    private async void InitializeCamera()
    {
        // media capture creation

        _captureElement = new CaptureElement();
        _captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
        await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
}
```

`MediaCapture` should be included inside a service that represents the camera. I haven't included it to keep the solution simple.